# Where is defined behavior of `true` value for `schema`?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

The `enum` property for [draft-07](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html) is defined as:

```
    "enum": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": true,
        "minItems": 1,
        "uniqueItems": true
    },
```

But in the [SPEC](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.4.1) no definition for `true` value:

> The value of "items" MUST be either a valid JSON Schema or an array of valid JSON Schemas.

Link me please to the point where SPEC defines the behavior for validator when `true` is met in place of `schema`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.4.3.1

> The boolean schema values "true" and "false" are trivial assertions that always return themselves regardless of the instance value. As an example, in terms of the validation vocabulary, boolean schemas are equivalent to the following behaviors:
>
> true
>
> - Always passes validation, as if the empty schema {}
>
> false
>
> - Always fails validation, as if the schema { "not":{} }

Comment: Is there different definition for `empty schema` except this one?

Comment: `An empty schema is a JSON Schema with no properties, or only unknown properties.` is the official definition. An empty schema means there are no constraints. Any value is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean `true` value in itself is a valid JSON Schema, hence the enum specification conforms to its own spec.

For reference, the spec is defined as follows, explicitly allowing a boolean value at the root:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  ...
  "type": [
    "object",
    "boolean"
  ],
  ...
}
```

If we want to verify if `"items": true` is allowed, we need to first lookup the specification of the `items` property. This is formally defined as follows:

```
"items": {
    "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/schemaArray" }
    ],
    "default": true
},
```

This means that the allowed value for the `items` property is either a JSON Schema (since it references the root object of the spec schema) or that it is an array of JSON schemas).  In this case, we thus need to verify if `true` adheres to the root schema `#`, or to the `#/definitions/schemaArray` definition. Thus, let's first look at the root schema which specifies the type to be `["object", "boolean"]`. Since `true` is a boolean, we have successfully verified that the value `true` for the property `items` is indeed valid.

Comment: Still do not understand how to check enum `value` against `true`: *"items": true*. Should I just take the root schema and check this value against it?

Comment: @EugenKonkov I have tried to give a more detailed explanation on why it is allowed.

Comment: Did you see in question how items defined? I have no such definition as you provide in your explanation.

Comment: The shown schemas are the JSON Schema meta schema, showing you that boolean is allowed for a value of the `items` keyword.